# Tizen Studio Not Opening

Tags: eclipse, tizen, galaxy, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

So I've just downloaded Tizen Studio for the second time. The first time, Tizen Studio wouldn't open and neither would the Package Manager. After deleting all files and reinstalling, the Package Manager opens but Tizen Studio still does not. In the ide folder of Tizen Studio I can run the eclipse.exe and that opens just fine but I get nothing from the TizenStudio.exe.

I am on Windows 10, my JDK is OpenJDK 10.

Anyone have idea what might be going on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Because this issue can be caused for another reason that I've found, and this thread is one of the top google results, I'd like to point out that if Tizen Studio still does not open after JDK 8 is installed, make sure that you installed Tizen to a file path without ANY spaces, as this will crash it before any GUI appears.

Comment: I put Tizen under my "Program Files" folder and I had to move it out. This fixed the IDE not loading for me.  I would try this BEFORE messing with Java versions and paths.

Comment: Can't believe it's working now after changing folder name from `Tizen Studio` to `tizen-studio`

Answer (score 0):

Oracle JDK 8 is recommended. Try again with Oracle JDK 8.

Comment: There is no information about it on [developer.tizen.org](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/download/installing-tizen-studio/prerequisites?langredirect=1) Where did You find this?

Comment: Actually, It is based on my experience. I had heard that long time ago at some community offline event.

Answer (score 0):

If you have OpenJDK 10 instead of Oracle JDK 8, install OpenJFX as well.

The link you supplied ( https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/download/installing-tizen-studio/prerequisites?langredirect=1 ) states it at the end of "Java Development Kit (JDK) Requirements" section.